# NullPointerException When Reading Directory Contents in Java

Tags: java, file, object, directory

My code is giving me a `NullPointerException` when it reads from a directory. It reads the first 2 directories fine (DirFolder1 and DirFolder2), but it also doesn't display DirFolder3's contents either. What I'm missing pretty much is DirFolder4 and DirFolder3's contents. I don't understand why this exception is happening when it finds the 4th directory. I'm also pushing a new object to hold the directory name, file name, and child directory name. How to I get multiple directories to read their contents in the same parent folder?

**Main File:**

```
import java.io.IOException;
public class DirectoryRead {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        MyOwnObject x = new MyOwnObject();
        x.read();
    }
}
```

**Directory Read File:**

```
import java.io.File;

public class MyOwnObject {
    String dirName = "";
    String fileName = "";
    String childName = "";
    
    public void read() {
        MyOwnObject x = new MyOwnObject(); 
        ArrayBoundedStack<MyOwnObject> stack = new ArrayBoundedStack<MyOwnObject>();
        
        File parent = new File("C:\\DirFolder1");
        dirName = parent.getPath();
        
        stack.push(x);
        
        while (!stack.isEmpty()) {
            File current = new File(dirName, childName);
            System.out.println(current.getName());
            stack.pop();
            
            File [] files = current.listFiles();

            for (File f : files) {
                if (f.isDirectory()) {
                    childName = f.getName();
                    System.out.println("\t" + childName);
                    stack.push(new MyOwnObject());
                }
                else {
                    fileName = f.getName();
                    System.out.println("\t" + fileName);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
DirFolder1
    DirFolder2
    Sample File1.txt
DirFolder2
    DirFolder3
    DirFolder4
    Document2.txt
    Document3.txt
DirFolder4
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at MyOwnObject.read(MyOwnObject.java:24)
    at DirectoryRead.main(DirectoryRead.java:6)
```

Comment: `listFiles()` will return `null` if the directory is empty. You need to add a check for that, to make sure your code doesn't try iterating over it if no files exist.

Comment: Regarding DirFolder3: Use your IDE's debugger and single-step through the program. Especially watch the moment when it gets to "DirFolder3", and what it does (or fails to do) with that folder. By the way, you might also want to have a close look on the elements stored in your `stack`.